# Listview Scrolling to widget with variable height

Tags: flutter

I have a Listview filled with Text Widgets of variable height:

```
ListView.builder(
    controller: _controller,
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(items[index].text));
    })
```

I use a ScrollController (_controller) to animate the list and scroll down when the user clicks a button.

```
_moveDown() {
    _controller.animateTo(_controller.offset + 100,
    curve: Curves.linear, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100));
}
```

I have no issues scrolling in fixed increments (100px in the example above), but I can't figure out how to calculate the height of the widgets in the list so the user can scroll among the list items.

Is there a way to get the height of each of the elements of the list?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, there is.**

You need to give a `Key`, for example a `GlobalKey` to your child widget, which by your example, looks like a `Padding`, then you can find the `height` of the rendering widget. Your method to handle your scroll could then be something like this where `myKey` is each items key.

```
 void _moveDown(GlobalKey myKey) {
    final keyContext = myKey.currentContext;

    if (keyContext != null) {
      final box = keyContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.offset + box.size.height,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.linear);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @miguelpruvio - how do I assign those keys? I've seen examples doing exactly what you explain, but they don't deal with multiple items

Comment: Are the items of the list all of the same height?

Comment: No, that is the issue ;)